# Stored Proc to return data based on sum of 3 columns of the proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored proc as follows:

```
SELECT   DiscountId         
        ,Discount1
        ,Discount2
        ,Discount3            
    FROM    PriceDiscount
```

This can return 0 or one or more rows.
I need to check the aggregate of Discount1,Discount2 and Discount3. If **sum for any of the rows is greater than 0**, I want to set a field isDiscounted = true and return it also. 
For instance, the following will return isDiscounted=true since total for one of the rows is greater than 0.

```
Discount1 Discount2  Discount3  TotalDiscount
34.00      0.00       0.00      34.00
0.00       0.00       0.00      0.00
0.00       0.00       0.00      0.00
```

I do not want to check this in the code or create another stored proc for this. 
I can add another column that aggregates as follows:

```
SELECT   DiscountId         
            ,Discount1
            ,Discount2
            ,Discount3 
            ,(Discount1+Discount2+Discount3) as TotalDiscount             
        FROM    PriceDiscount
```

Now how should I check whether one of the TotalDiscount is >0 and return isDiscounted as true or false?

Comment: Use a case statement

Comment: For your sample Isnt clear to me if you want group all rows or each row will have a field `isDiscount` ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a case statement. Add this field:

```
,CASE WHEN (Discount1+Discount2+Discount3) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isDiscounted
```

Answer (score 0):

This version is for all rows.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/48422/1)**

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN SUM(Discount1) + SUM(Discount2) + SUM(Discount3) > 0 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END as isDiscount
FROM PriceDiscount;
```